# how to call Cufon.refresh after user click on <h:commandButton>

Tags: jsf, cufon

In my project i have a `<h:datatabel>` that contains details of polls that defined in the system. I will use pagination in my page, then create use a next command with the following code:

```
<h:commandLink value="&lt;" action="#{PollSearchControler.next}" >
    <f:ajax render="checkall"  />
</h:commandLink>
```

my button work good and when i click in it my table refresh and load new data. but i have a problem with `Cufon`. I use `Cufon` in my project for use non standard font. when my date changed, i must call `Cufon.refresh()`. this function render new data and show my data with my font. now i have a question:
How can i say to `<f:ajax>` that call `Cufon.refresh()` after it load new data?
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the onevent attribute to call a javascript function, this function will be called three times during the request lifetime: begin, complete, success. for example  `<f:ajax render="checkall"  onevent="refreshCuffon"/>`
and the function will be

```
function refreshCuffon(data) {
   if(data.status == "success") { 
       Cufon.refresh()
   }
}
```